# Plain text editor in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: visual-studio-2015

It's not make or break, but I'd like to know if it's possible to add in a text editor as a Window in Visual Studio 2015, that I can use side-by-side with the code? There are many view windows; Properties, Output, Solution Explorer, etc., but I haven't found a text editor view window. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Have you tried just dragging a .txt file into it? That works for me.

Comment: I've tried that, but I can't get it to drag into the program for some reason. Do you mean a regular notepad file?

Comment: Yes. Alternatively, you could try Ctrl + O, or Ctrl + N and choose Text File under General? I guess it might also depend on what type of project you're using, I'm just in a standard C# console application to try it.

Answer (score 3):

The code editing window is the/a "text editor" window.

Just open a text file and edit it like you would any other file (ie: File -> Open).

Once you have a couple files open, if you want a split view, right-click one of the tabs and choose "New Vertical (or Horizontal) Tab Group":

[image]